# Rails ActiveRecord query does not use all required relations in `FROM`

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to maintain/fix an outdated plugin ([redmine_backlogs](https://github.com/AlexDAlexeev/redmine_backlogs/)) in Redmine for my company's productivity workflow; I am not even remotely conversant in the subtleties of Ruby (let alone Rails), but by virtue of having glanced at the code, I am the company guru on the matter... so.

Upfront clarity: *I'm looking for help on troubleshooting Ruby on Rails code* - namely:

> The application I am debugging is doing something like
>
> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA WHERE tableB.id = ? ...`
>
> whereas I am expecting of course
>
> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA,tableB WHERE tableB.id = ? ...`

The log reads as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'releases.id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `projects` WHERE (projects.status <> 9) AND (releases.id = 10 OR (projects.status <> 9 AND ( 'system' = 'none'  OR (projects.lft >= 91 AND projects.rgt <= 92 AND 'none' = 'tree') OR (projects.lft > 91 AND projects.rgt < 92 AND 'none' IN ('hierarchy', 'descendants')) OR (projects.lft < 91 AND projects.rgt > 92 AND 'none' = 'hierarchy'))))):
  plugins/redmine_backlogs/app/controllers/rb_master_backlogs_controller.rb:43:in `_menu_new'
  plugins/redmine_backlogs/app/controllers/rb_master_backlogs_controller.rb:62:in `menu'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

The active record item comes from this section of code in `plugins/redmine_backlogs/app/controllers/rb_master_backlogs_controller.rb`

```
...
      elsif @release #menu for release
        projects = @release.shared_to_projects(@project)

      else #menu for product backlog
        projects = @project.projects_in_shared_product_backlog

      end
      #make the submenu or single link
      if !projects.empty?                          # <<<<<<<<<<<< ----------------------- Line 43 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        if projects.length > 1
          links << {:label => l(label_new), :url => '#', :sub => []}
...
```

The `projects` object being tested for emptiness is generated by the call to `@release.shared_to_project` which is defined in `./app/models/rb_release.rb`, whose relevant sections are:

```
class RbRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  unloadable

  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :releases        # <<<<<<<---- Is this where the association is being asserted ?
  has_many :issues, :class_name => 'RbStory', :foreign_key => 'release_id', :dependent => :nullify
  has_many :rb_release_burnchart_day_cache, :dependent => :delete_all, :foreign_key => 'release_id'

  validates_presence_of :project_id, :name, :release_start_date, :release_end_date       # <<<<------- or here ....?
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => RELEASE_STATUSES
  validates_inclusion_of :sharing, :in => RELEASE_SHARINGS

...

  def shared_to_projects(scope_project)
    @shared_projects ||=
      begin
    # Project used when fetching tree sharing
    r = self.project.root? ? self.project : self.project.root
    # Project used for other sharings
    p = self.project
    Project.visible.scoped(:include => :releases,
      :conditions => ["#{RbRelease.table_name}.id = #{id}" +
      " OR (#{Project.table_name}.status <> #{Project::STATUS_ARCHIVED} AND (" +
      " 'system' = ? " +
      " OR (#{Project.table_name}.lft >= #{r.lft} AND
...
```

So evidently we're relying on something from the main `Project` object to do something with the templated query - checking `../../app/models/project.rb` I reach a dead end as to what to check for next... The `RbRelease` has declared its association with `Project`, but still the query does not seem to include that in the `FROM` clause before stating its conditions.

My naive question is: **how would I fix the relationship association so that the SQL query is correctly built ?**

`==============`

*(previously there was also this issue as part of the question, but it turned out to be unrelated)*

```
Started GET "/redmine/rb/master_backlog/afcd123_ghg/menu?project_id=9&authenticity_token=<REDACTED>" for 10.0.3.1 at 2017-06-21 15:21:36 +0000
Processing by RbMasterBacklogsController#menu as JSON
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"afcd123_ghg", "authenticity_token"=>"<REDACTED>"}
  Current user: tai (id=125)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#first with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call #first on it instead. (called from rb_project_settings at /usr/share/redmine/plugins/redmine_backlogs/lib/backlogs_project_patch.rb:193)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Comment: This line `RbProjectSettings.first(:conditions => ["project_id = ?", self.id])` can just be `RbProjectSettings.where(project_id: self.id).first` not sure if that solves all your problems as this is a long question and includes, what is in my opinion, some very ugly code

Comment: That got rid of the warning - but the relation is not fixed (crux of the issue) so I still have the SQL error ....

Answer (score 0):

This issue was very application specific; I post the actual solution here as I managed to track down someone else who has been maintaining this plugin.

The relationship has to be explicitly state in a `joins()` method call, on to which the rest gets tacked.

That is, stating a relationship **does not** have any sway on this query, as it is a direct query on the `Projects` object.

```
    Project.visible.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN releases ON releases.project_id = projects.id').
      includes(:releases).
      where("#{RbRelease.table_name}.id = #{id}" +
...
```